# How change sql_mode permanently on MariaDB on Debian 10?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, debian

I would like to change `sql_mode` to `NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION` permanently.

I already try to add `sql_mode = "NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"` on `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but nothing happens.

I'm using: `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2`

Comment: Did you add it under [mysqld] ? Have you restarted it after changing settings?

Comment: @kopz yes. Under [mysqld] and restarted and reboot after changing and nothing happens.